# MySQL: efficient query on a column too long to be indexed

Tags: mysql, sql

In my MySQL database, I have a string column (*for example*, an SHA hash) which grows too long to put an index on. How can I run efficient queries against this column?

- I can put an index on the first `N` characters of the column, but then what does the query that makes use of this "partial" index look like?
- I could create a second column with `N` characters and put a full index on that, as a surrogate for a "partial" index. I would then query, get one or more records, and do the final step of the filtering in memory.
- I can use [full text search functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), but then I need to use MyISAM. MyISAM does not support ACIDity, therefore no thank you.

What is a proper way to achieve this in MySQL?

The question is not about reducing the size of my column or reconfiguring my database if it's configured with a too short key length. It's about leveraging a partial index or something of the kind painlessly, preferably without putting a burden on the application or popping up additional columns.

In my particular case, I am looking for a composite key on two columns in a UTF8 table:

```
create table fingerprinted_item (
  type varchar (512) not null,
  fingerprint varchar (512) not null,
  primary key (fingerprint, type)
);

-- Then there may be a child table.
```

MySQL says:

```
[42000][1071] Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

On a different server, the max key length is 1000 bytes.

Comment: What do you mean "grows too long to put an index on"?  According to who?

Comment: @alexn: For the sake of argument, a 512 character secure hash, maybe SHA, maybe something else, which exceeds the index size limits. BTW, the character set on the table is UTF-8 (which may cause MySQL to assume several bytes per char if it actually stores in something like UCS-2).

Comment: Could you provide some more information on that "string column too long", as [MyISAM keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/myisam-storage-engine.html) have a max. length of 1000 bytes, and [InnoDB keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html) could grow up to 3072 bytes. Quite long for a SHA hash...

Comment: @AndyLester: it's simply too long and MySQL complains that it can't put an index because the byte limit for indices (even though this is a varchar) has been exceeded.

Comment: @MihaiDanila 512 bytes is well below the max index size both for MyISAM and InnoDB. Could you show the statement that cause issues and the corresponding error message?

Comment: `create table fingerprinted_entry (
  type varchar (128) not null, -- I would actually like this to be much longer, really
  fingerprint varchar (512) not null,
  primary key (fingerprint, type)
);`

Comment: `[2013-08-20 16:54:48] [42000][1071] Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes`

Comment: I updated the question. I'm not trying to understand why my "SHA" doesn't fit in the index. I'm trying to run efficient queries on long columns, period. Forget the SHA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The real issue is probably to use `VARCHAR` for the fingerprint column. When using the utf8 character encoding, MySQL enforces the "worst case scenario" and counts 3 bytes per character.

Either change that to 1-byte encoding (say Latin1), or use the `VARBINARY` type instead:

```
create table fingerprinted_entry 
( type varchar (128) not null, 
  fingerprint varbinary (512) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY(type, fingerprint)) ENGINE InnoDB; -- no error here
```

---

If you have to go beyond the 767 byte limit per prefix, you will have to *explicitly* state that when you create the index:

```
create table fingerprinted_entry 
( type varchar (128) not null, 
  fingerprint varbinary (2048) not null,              -- 2048 bytes
  PRIMARY KEY(type, fingerprint(767))) ENGINE InnoDB; -- only the first 767 bytes of fingerprint are stored in the index
```

Comment: Changing the encoding is not an option. Your second example suggests that the limit on the index length is in bytes -- good thing to know. In your answer, you changed the size of the `type` column -- is that intentional? If I have 6 columns in a primary key, do I need to put all of them in `VARBINARY` mode? Finally, the fact that I cannot ensure uniqueness puts a burden on my application -- is there really no better way in the 21st century to give a value and get back the row corresponding to it? This DBMS is free for use, true, but still.

Comment: Was trying to understand why `utf8` (presumably UTF-8, a variable length Unicode encoding) is stored as 3 bytes, and lo and behold I find that not all of Unicode can be stored in MySQL's `utf8`-encoded tables. What in the world??? Are these MySQL guys into bad jokes? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html

Answer (score 2):

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=6604

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` ADD UNIQUE ( yourcolumn(1000))
```

Play around with the last parameter.

Comment: Doh, that confirms what I feared. It stores Unicode internally in some sparse format, quickly eating up the bytes. You're suggesting a partial index, but now for the remaining piece: how do I write a query that makes this index kick in? Do I use MySQL substring functions?

Comment: @MihaiDanila: The index will always "kick in" when you operate based on the column, just like if it wasn't partial. It just won't technically force the column to be unique beyond the first n characters. (you should use varbinary for fingerprints and such though, otherwise you'll also get case insensitive comparisons by default)

Comment: @Kris: so if I have a two character column and an index on the first character and my select says `where myColumn = 'ab'`, then MySQL will use the index to find all the rows starting with an `a` and then go through each of these to find the `ab`?

Comment: @MihaiDanila: yes. As far as I understand it, and consistent with what I have observed.